# RewriteRule subdomain ignored if request URI points to a file/folder in root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I setup subdomains with .htaccess so that sub.domain.com points to /sub/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule (.*) /sub/$1 [L]
```

The problem is - let's say I have two folders *sub* and *xyz*. Now if I go to *sub.domain.com/xyz*, apache will go to the */xyz/* folder in root instead of */sub/xyz/* (presumably since it has special handling of existing files and folders in the URI).

Is there a way I can use .htaccess in the root folder to stop this behavior without having access to apache configs? Basically always rewrite subdomains to their folders even if the URI points to an existing resource in the root folder instead of the subdomain folder.

I know I could create a separate folder for subdomains and solve it that way, but there are a couple reasons I have it done like this:

1. I used to have subdomains handled by the hosting's configuration, where it would automatically rewrite *folder.domain.com* to */folder/* using some magic apache configuration instead of htaccess. This setup did not cause the issue.
2. Since that was my original setup, I have a couple PHP scripts that use relative paths to go back. I could change that and a couple other things, but there's no reason if there is an easy solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used [Apache `httpd`](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd) in years (there's been no need to since [`nginx`](http://ports.su/www/nginx) came about!), but I don't think it has any sort of *"special handling of existing files and folders in the URI"*.

I find it more likely that you're omitting the information about something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, which would condition your `RewriteRule` to not apply in the case of the directory being requested in the URI already existing prior to the application of the rewrite rule itself.

Comment: None of the subdomain rules have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.

Comment: @chylex, you have to provide more details, then.  there must be something in your setup that's causing the described behaviour, because Apache doesn't have the "special handling" that you describe

Comment: I have a feeling it's something on my hosting's side then, they have special handling of folder subdomains that you can toggle, but ever since they did some changes on my account the toggle stopped working (it was disabled and is disabled now, but I can't enable it anymore). I bit the bullet and reorganized the folders completely yesterday, I'll let the hosting know something is broken (even though I asked them about this issue already and they didn't know what was going on).

Comment: It sounds like maybe your `.htaccess` was at the wrong directory level; anyhow, it looks like this problem is gone...  please upvote and accept! :-)  I just +1'ed your question, so you now have a rep of +16 and can upvote other posts! ;)

Comment: I sent a message to my hosting, it definitely sounds like an issue on their side. I would still like to know why it didn't work (the problem is still here, I just "hid" it away). Guessing it's some apache mod or configuration issue.